# Why is this random process stationary?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

I am studying stationary from wikipedia. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process?wprov=sfii1)

In the examples section, the following is written.

let $Y$ have a uniform distribution on $(0,2π]$ and define the time series $\{ X_t \}$ by

$X_t=\cos (t+Y) \quad \text{ for } t \in \mathbb{R}$. 
Then $\{ X_t \}$ is strictly stationary.

I don't understand why it is stationary.

Can someone prove this?

Comment: Yes. // Can you write down the property you are supposed to establish?

Comment: @Did I just want to understand the exact definition and differences of the 1st-order, 2nd-order, wide sense, and strict sense stationary. Some sites define them using Expectation, some using Set, some sites using Sequence, some sites using mean and variance, even some sites using signal power. I decided to believe wikipedia's definition but I do not understand why $X_t=\cos{(t+Y)}$ is strictly stationary.

Comment: IOW, you have no idea what you are supposed to show? Then the mention "I don't understand why it is stationa(r)y" is misleading and should read "I don't understand what is stationarity". And to that, the best answer might be to look for a *definition*, no? So, back to square one: what is the definition of stationarity in this context?

Comment: @Did First, sorry for vague question. According to wikipedia, definition of stationary is $F_X(x_{t_1+\tau}, \cdots, x_{t_k+\tau} = F_X(x_{t_1}, \cdots, x_{t_k}$. So I tried to prove that $X_t=\cos{(t+Y)}$ is strictly stationary using this definition. But I failed. I might have been able to solve this if not sinusoidal function but common polynomial function.

Comment: ?? Sorry but what is your definition of $F_X(x_{t_1},\ldots,x_{t_k})$?

Comment: @Did Ah, $F_X$ is c.d.f. of $(x_{t_1}, \cdots, x_{t_k}$).

Comment: Huh? $(x_{t_1},\ldots,x_{t_k})$ is a tuple of *real numbers*, these cannot have a CDF, right?

Comment: @Did $(x_{t_1}, \cdots, x_{t_k}$ doesn't have CDF? I maybe think of random process totally wrong. I will read textbook again! thank you

Comment: @Did F_X is the joint cumulative distribution of $\{X_{t_k}\}_k$ where $X_{t_k}=\cos(Y+t_k)$

Comment: @hkBst I know this is what should be understood. The trouble is that this does not relate to what the OP is writing. (Additionally, note that $X_t$ is defined for every $t$ hence $F_X$ should not depend on the choice of a tuple $(t_1,\ldots,t_k)$. As a rule, imprecision in the notations reflects imprecision in the understanding of the notions involved.)

Comment: @Did I am really sorry but can I ask what the OP means? In my dictionary, op is opera, operation, operator, opposite, etc. but I think OP is different from them in this context.

Comment: @Danny_Kim, Original Poster, in this case you :)

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4090/what-does-op-mean

Comment: Thank you. As far as I am concerned, English has so many abbreviations that it makes me difficult to understand. T.T Especially, short abbreviations have too many words to find what the original word is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the cosine is periodic with period 2$\pi$, $Y$ already covers all possible inputs within a whole period of the cosine, and so does $Y+t$.

A formal proof:

We need to show that $P(\cos(Y)\le x) = P(\cos(Y+t)\le x)$. We have:
$P(\cos(Y)\le x)2\pi = I_{]1, \infty]}(x)2\pi + I_{[-1,1]}(x)\mu(\{y\in]0,2\pi]|\cos(y)\le x\})$
and
$P(\cos(Y+t)\le x)2\pi = I_{]1, \infty]}(x)2\pi + I_{[-1,1]}(x)\mu(\{y\in]0,2\pi]|\cos(y+t)\le x\})$.

If $x \in [-1,1]$, then $\arccos(x)$ exists and we have:

$\mu(\{y\in]0,2\pi]|\cos(y)\le x\}) = I_{[-1,1]}(x)\mu(\{]0,2\pi]\cap\bigcup_{k\in\mathbf{Z}}[\arccos(x)+2k\pi,2\pi-\arccos(x)+2k\pi]\}) = \mu(\{]0,t]\cup]t,2\pi]\cap\bigcup_{k\in\mathbf{Z}}[\arccos(x)+2k\pi,2\pi-\arccos(x)+2k\pi]\}) = \mu(\{(]t,2\pi]\cup]2\pi,t+2\pi])\cap\bigcup_{k\in\mathbf{Z}}[\arccos(x)+2k\pi,2\pi-\arccos(x)+2k\pi]\}) = \mu(\{]t,t+2\pi]\cap\bigcup_{k\in\mathbf{Z}}[\arccos(x)+2k\pi,2\pi-\arccos(x)+2k\pi]\}) = \mu(\{]0,2\pi]\cap\bigcup_{k\in\mathbf{Z}}[\arccos(x)+2k\pi-t,2\pi-\arccos(x)+2k\pi-t]\}) = \mu(\{y\in]0,2\pi]|\cos(y+t)\le x\})$

We further need to show that $P(X_{t_1+\tau} \le x_1, \ldots, X_{t_n+\tau} \le x_n) = P(X_{t_1} \le x_1, \ldots, X_{t_n} \le x_n)$ for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: Is it enough to say that it is strictly stationary? I tried to change domain from $X$ to $Y$ using Jacobian matrix. but it is so hard to continue to prove because arc-sinusoidal function appeared in my process. Anyhow, thank you for giving me some intuition.

Comment: @Danny_Kim, I added a formal proof.

Comment: This is weak stationarity. Strict stationarity is the fact that the distribution of $(X_{t_1+s},\ldots,X_{t_k+s})$ does not depend on $s$, for every $k$ and every $(t_1,\ldots,t_k)$.

Comment: @Did, you are right that it is not yet strict stationarity...

Comment: @hkBst When I saw this answer first, I felt fears. But now I am analyzing your proof. This is good for understanding about WSS. Thank you. Can i ask about ]a, b]?

Comment: @Danny_Kim, ]a,b] is just the half-open interval, same as (a,b]. In any case whether the end-points are included or not does not matter anyway, since we always take the measure of these sets which is not sensitive to such differences...

Comment: Ah I got it thank you.